# Image Extraction : uri is too long

Tags: c#, uri, image-extraction

I am working on Image Extraction Software from A WebPage . have created a function

```
 public static void GetAllImages()
        {

            WebClient x = new WebClient();
            string source = x.DownloadString(@"http://www.bbc.com");

            var document = new HtmlWeb().Load(source);
            var urls = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
                                .Select(e => e.GetAttributeValue("src", null))
                                .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s));

            document.Load(source);


        }
```

It says "Uri is too long " ..

I tried to use Uri.EscapeDataString .. But not getting idea where to put it

Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: Where/when does it say that the Uri is too long?

Comment: on var document = new HtmlWeb().Load(source);

Comment: My bet is that HtmlWeb.Load takes Uri as its parameter while you are feeding it the whole page contents.
Also please add description of HtmlWeb class to your question. You're probably using some sore of 3rd party library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HtmlWeb.Load` takes a **URL** as its source and deals with the downloading of the content. You don't need a supplementary `WebClient` to do this, it's all taken care of.

What you are doing is downloading the content, then attempting to use the downloaded content (HTML) as a URL (probably under the assumption that `Load` means `Parse`).

So remove

```
WebClient x = new WebClient();
string source = x.DownloadString(@"http://www.bbc.com");
```

then change the next line to

```
var document = new HtmlWeb().Load(@"http://www.bbc.com");
```

and you'll be good to go.